# BeautifulSoup returning different html - not a final result (python)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pip

I'm trying to parse 'Company description' data from given url;
https://www.ubisoft.com/en-us/careers/search.aspx#sr-post-id=743999734133930,
but the html fetched by soup is different than what I see in the browser. What I get is a language selection (which I guess happens under the hood on page visit). How can I get the 'final' data for this url?
Here's the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 500)
import time
import requests
import random

page = requests.get("https://api.smartrecruiters.com/v1/companies/Ubisoft2/postings?limit=100&offset=1600&_=1612802051149")
page
soup = bs(page.content)
record_el = soup('body')[0]
```

Additionally, is there any other solution that comes to mind for similar task (scraping thematic data from various websites, such as 'company description' in case described above)?
Thanks!

Comment: You would have to use an active we driver, for example selenium or playwright. That will open the webpage as if it is in a browser (it actually is) and then you can extract the source once the page is fully loaded. You can insert that in Beautifulsoup.

Comment: @JarroVGIT Thanks! That did it :)
Here's my code:

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time
import requests
import random

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.ubisoft.com/en-us/careers/search.aspx#sr-post-id=743999734133930")
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = bs(page_source);
`

Comment: It is better to use the [edit] button to improve your question rather than adding code as a comment, or if you have solved your own question, you can add your own answer below